# Imported Selenium IDE script fails

Tags: selenium-ide, katalon-studio, katalon-recorder

I am testing out Katalon Recorder and Studio to see if they can handle imported Selenium IDE scripts. I executed the following directions successfully:

> https://forum.katalon.com/discussion/4220/how-to-import-selenium-ide-test-cases-into-katalon-studio

However, the moment I click RUN I receive the following error message:

> 01-24-2018 06:33:12 PM - [START]  - Start Test Case : Test Cases/New Test Case
>
> 01-24-2018 06:33:12 PM - [INFO]   - Evaluating variables for test case
>
> 01-24-2018 06:33:13 PM - [ERROR]  - Test Cases/New Test Case FAILED because (of) org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
>
> General error during class generation: Method code too large!
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Method code too large!
>
> at groovyjarjarasm.asm.MethodWriter.a(Unknown Source)
>
> at groovyjarjarasm.asm.ClassWriter.toByteArray(Unknown Source)
>
> at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$16.call(CompilationUnit.java:815)
>
> at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:1053)
>
> at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:591)
>
> at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:569)
>
> at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:546)
>
> etc...

I have no clue what this means. I appreciate any help.

Comment: You should try 5.3 version, which add a new feature called 'Import Selenium IDE Scripts'